# Angular2,Ionic2 :How to get static star ratings in angular 2 for values in database?

Tags: angular, typescript, static, ionic2, rating-system

I want to display star ratings for values in a REST API. For every product my API contains a parameter called ratings which ranges from 1-5.

I'm only able to find the code for clickable ratings. But I want to show that value in the form of stars from 1-5. Like how we have stars for movie ratings or product ratings.

I found this link but it is for Angular1
[Rendering a Star Rating System using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646395/rendering-a-star-rating-system-using-angularjs)

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445400/7088500) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438098/ionic2-angular2-dynamic-rate-value-with-ion-icon-star?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Angular Bootstrap library. 
Simply install it with npm command like this:
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
Don't forget to import to your module:
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NgbModule, ...],
  ...
})

Check the official documentation for the reference:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples